# Display images with carousel in Django

Tags: django, django-templates

I have problems while displaying my images, the same image is always printed on the carousel.

Image URLs have not problem bot I see only one and the same image in my carousel. I know there are 3 different images because of for loop but when I delete it, the carousel is not work

The method I tried is below.

```
{% for i in ads%}
<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="/image/{{i.image_ads}}" class="d-block w-100" alt="Image no:1">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="/image/{{i.image_ads}}"class="d-block w-100" alt="Image no:2">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="/image/{{i.image_ads}}"class="d-block w-100" alt="Image no:3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{%endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your for loop inside the carousel div.

```
<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    {% for i in ads%}
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="/image/{{i.image_ads}}" class="d-block w-100" alt="Image no:{{ forloop.counter }}">
    </div>
    {%endfor %} 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but now I can only view a single image with this method and it doesn't move. I have several images.

Comment: Then I think maybe you need to provide more information in the question about how your `ads` object is structured. Also, do you want one carousel, or multiple carousels?

Comment: I want to use one carousel and ads has only name and  image_ads = models.ImageField(upload_to='image',blank=True,verbose_name="Image of Ad")  this model type.

Comment: Then I think my answer is the correct one. The problem may be with your carousel, not the Django. The loop as I have written it should add `carousel-item` three times if you have three images.

Answer (score 0):

When rendering data to the templates through database for carousel, the active class seems to create a problem for many of the beginners. When you use for loop logic to iterate over your slider in the front end, the loop will create three carousels with class set active to each. To avoid this you can use if-else syntax inside the for loop. A simple example would be this one.

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    {% for j in image_slider %}
          <!--You need to add forloop here -->
            <div class="carousel-item {% if forloop.first %} active {% endif %}">
                <img src="{{j.slider_img.url}}">
                <div class="carousel-caption text-center">
                    <h1>{{j.main_heading}}</h1>
                    <h3>{{j.sub_heading}}</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

[check here for more detail](https://beta.peakd.com/hive-163521/@leoumesh/looping-through-carousel-in-django-python)